# Proof of irrationality of infinite continued fractions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, trigonometry, pi

We have the identity
$$\tan x=\frac{x}{1+\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\mathrm K}} \frac{-x^2}{2n+1}}.$$
From the Wikipedia article on *Proof that π is irrational*:

> [...] Lambert proved that if *x* is non-zero and rational then this expression must be irrational.

But how can we prove Lambert's assertion? I couldn't find any resource containing the proof.

Comment: Side note: the two statements in yellow boxes are not equivalent. The second statement must be wrong because there are way more irrationals than rationnals.

Comment: No, it's certainly not an if and only if.  There are countably many rationals, so for all but countably many irrational $x$ the expression is irrational.

Comment: Alright, I will correct that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: By the way, that fraction in your post is not an example of a [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction), it's just a fraction with an infinite sum in the denominator. See [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/10/) for some continued fraction expansions of the tangent function.

Comment: @LeeMosher Note the $K$ rather than a $\Sigma$. Also I believe he's written it slightly wrong; it should be $1 + \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\mathrm K}} \frac{-x^2}{2n+1}$.

Comment: Are you sure that it is an infinite sum? The $\mathrm K$ is Gauss' compact notation for continued fractions. For more details, see the "Notation" section   here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

Comment: You may have a look at my [blog post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/05/irrationality-of-pi-lamberts-proof.html?m=0).

Comment: Alright then, thanks for the heads up. Not a familiar notation to me, but I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x=\frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. Then
$$\tan\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a}{b+\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\mathrm K}} \frac{-a^2}{(2n+1)b}}.$$
Let $3b\gt a^2$ (this can be assumed without loss of generality, if $3b\le a^2$ then for large enough $n$ it's true that $(2n+1)b\gt a^2$), which means that
$$0\lt \frac{a^2}{3b+\underset{n=2}{\overset{\infty}{\mathrm K}} \tfrac{-a^2}{(2n+1)b}}\lt 1.$$
Now if
$$\frac{a^2}{3b+\underset{n=2}{\overset{\infty}{\mathrm K}} \tfrac{-a^2}{(2n+1)b}}=\frac{c_2}{c_1}$$
for some $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0\lt\frac{c_2}{c_1}\lt 1$, then $c_1\gt c_2$. Furthermore,
$$0\lt\frac{c_{3}}{c_{2}}=\frac{a^2}{5b+\underset{n=3}{\overset{\infty}{\mathrm K}} \tfrac{-a^2}{(2n+1)b}}\lt 1,$$
$c_{3}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $c_2\gt c_3$, and so on:
$$c_1\gt c_2\gt c_3\gt\cdots\gt 0.$$
This is a contradiction since $c_{k\gt 0}$ are natural numbers, so
$$\frac{a^2}{3b+\underset{n=2}{\overset{\infty}{\mathrm K}} \tfrac{-a^2}{(2n+1)b}}\ne\frac{c_2}{c_1}\implies \tan\frac{a}{b}\notin\mathbb{Q}.$$
Thus we arrived at the conclusion that
$$x\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\implies \tan x\notin\mathbb{Q}.$$

Comment: Why do you assume $a^2<3b$?

Comment: It can be assumed without loss of generality. Also, you see that the denominators are bigger than numerators.

Comment: You should then explain in your answer why there should be no loss of generality. If you see my blog posts then you will find that this assumption is not really needed.

Comment: It seems that your blog is exactly what I needed. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: As for the generality, either $a^2\lt 3b$ or $a^2\gt 3b$ or $a^2=3b$. If $a^2=3b$, we'll move onto another fraction where we'll establish an inequality (compare $a^2$ with $5b,7b,\ldots$). If $a^2\gt 3b$, then the approach is analogous since if $x$ is rational, then $x^{-1}$ is rational. I'm not completely sure about the validity of this justification though.

Comment: If $a^2>3b$ then also move to $5b,7b$ etc. The key is that there is a value $n$ such that $a^2<(2n-1)b$.

Answer (score 1):

**I couldn't find any resource containing the proof.**

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Lambert's_proof) says that Lambert's proof may be found in

> Lambert, Johann Heinrich (2004) [1768], "Mémoire sur quelques propriétés remarquables des quantités transcendantes circulaires et logarithmiques", in Berggren, Lennart; Borwein, Jonathan M.; Borwein, Peter B. (eds.), Pi, a source book (3rd ed.), New York: Springer-Verlag, pp. 129–140, ISBN 0-387-20571-3

Comment: Actually I meant resources that are freely accessible.